# Animate icon font spinner

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I've created 12 glyphs in my custom icon font to represent every tick of a loading spinner (OSX/iOS style).

The markup looks something like this

```
<div class="spinner">
  <span class="c1">&#xf001</span>
  ...
  <span class="c12">&#xf012</span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.spinner {
  font-family: "nvicons";
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: -1em;
  .c1 {
    color: #eee;
  }

  ...

  .c12 {
    color: #222;
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to animate the colors if the tick glyphs, but unfortunately the `color` css attribute doesn't seem animatable and `background` seems to be of no help in this case. Further I didn't find a way to animate with keyframes, since the animation is smooth and not edgy like I would need it to be.

Is there a possibility to animate this with CSS? What I need to do is cycle the colors around somehow and I really want to avoid JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution. Put it together on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsy3g/)

```
.spinner {
    position: relative;
    font-family:"nvicons";
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: -1em;
    color: #eee;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
.spinner > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: coloring 1s linear infinite;
}
.spinner .e1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.0s;
}
.spinner .e2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.08333s;
}
.spinner .e3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.16667s;
}
.spinner .e4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.spinner .e5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.33333s;
}
.spinner .e6 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.41667s;
}
.spinner .e7 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.spinner .e8 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.58333s;
}
.spinner .e9 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.66667s;
}
.spinner .e10 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.spinner .e11 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.83333s;
}
.spinner .e12 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.91667s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes coloring {
    from {
        color: #222;
    }
    to {
        color: #eee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am noy sure if I get all the requirements, but I would say that you are trying to change the color of the elements in a sequence.

When you say that you want the animation to be edgy and not smooth, that can be done with keyframes, it just gives you a little more work. You only need to create duplicate steps very close to the other:

```
@-webkit-keyframes colors {
    0%   {color: red;}
    49%  {color: red;}
    50%  {color: blue;}
    100% {color: blue;}
```

}

notice that all the change from red to blue is between 49% and 50%

of course, that can be extensive to the number of steps that you want; only that you need to state every property twice.

also notice that I am indeed changing the color. a demo (only webkit):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Q6UPJ/1/)

**new answer**

Now that it's clear what you wanted, the best solution would be that one:

[example from one div web](http://one-div.com/pictos/ajax-loader/)

notice that at the end you are doing a rotation:

```
@-keyframes ajax-loader-rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

and to hide the intermediate steps (where the circles would be in intermediate positions) the animation is done by steps:

```
animation: .85s ajax-loader-rotate steps(8) infinite;
```

of course all of this with vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is position your spinner icon 12 times at a fixed distance around a point each 30 degrees apart from its adjacent pieces. Then change the background of the first piece (12 o'clock) to the 3rd darkest color you want to start the animation. Then after a set period of time for the animation, move the 3rd darkest color to the next piece as its background. If you can provide me with your icon font I'll make you a jsfiddle with it.

Comment: Without markup/css I don't understand your answer. You can assume that the pre-rotated ticks are unicode values `f001` to `f012`.

Comment: your answer is exactly what i said to do...and it's great, nice job!

Comment: i would have made you everything you needed if you gave me the icon font....like i said in my answer...